# ASP.NET MVC - How controls retain their state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewstate

There are some text boxes on my page. When I submit the page, the controls retain their state after postback. I know that ASP.NET MVC does not have a concept of viewstate. So how can it be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you submit the form values are sent along the request (in the URL if GET and in the request body if POST) and if the controller action renders the same view without redirecting the HTML helpers that were used to render those textboxes will fetch the values from the request show it. Indeed there's no such concept as viewstate.